# Colons in what looks like a JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

This example is from an in video [*Vue Router 4 for Everyone*](https://vueschool.io/lessons/the-scaffolded-codebase-vite-only) at 1'37". Notice (from the filename `vite.config.js`) that the context is JavaScript, not TypeScript.

```
export default defineConfig(config: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(pathSegments[0]: __dirname, pathSegments[1]: './src')
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```

I am wondering: what is the semantics of the two colons in what looks like a call?

Comment: Are you sure this was the *code*? Did the video show the code *editor* and the word `condfig` (with the semicolon after it) was more of a faded grey and not as popping as the rest of the text? Because if so, that was just the code editor parameter hint. It would show what the parameter is called, so the *code* would be `foo("hello")` but with the editor supplied hint there it would read `foo(greeting: "hello")` because that is what the parameter was named and it adds clarity to what the value passed in is used for.

Comment: Can you add a link to the video?

Comment: @Yogi Your comment was instrumental for getting across this hurdle. I hand not noticed the revision below the video by myself. Thank you. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'd accept that one.